# How store a large file into SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, blob

I want to store large files in `SQL Server 2012`. I have been suggested to use `BLOB`. All I want to do is to create a table which map the `Employee id` and the path of his `image` in database. Whenever user want to access the `image` he will get the path from the database first and then get the `image` from referenced database using `BLOB`.
Can you help me how to access different database from one database.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Also, are the users accessing the DB through the command line? Through SSMS? Through a web interface?

Comment: Through web interface. There are two methods for this. FILESTREAM, FILETABLE. Which one to use in above scenario.

Comment: What is a "large" file? How large is a typical file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking for large files (over 1 MB, but not a rule) you should use FILESTREAM ([Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) which stores the files on filesystem and not in the database itself. 
See [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933995%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for a guide to set up using FILESTREAM in your database.

As for your question "Can you help me how to access different database from one database." Referencing objects in SQL is done with dot notation like this

```
databasename.schemaname.tablename
```

So you can use it to reference objects (tables) in different databases. For more info see [Using Identifiers As Object Names](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) not to reiterate what's there already.